# How to call stored procedure in liferay?

Tags: stored-procedures, liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

I am referring [Using dynamic query in Liferay](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-custom-sql-queries) and using MySQL 5.5 but instead of custom queries involving multiple entities,we need to call a stored procedure.
We have created a sample procedure

```
delimiter //
Create Procedure proc_check (OUT count INT)
begin
select count(*) into count from lg_office ;
end//
```

In default.xml,containing custom queries,we have used

```
<sql id="de.uhh.l2g.plugins.service.persistence.ProducerFinder.findOfficeCount">
        <![CDATA[
            Call proc_check(@output)
        ]]>
    </sql>
```

In the respective Finder method,we used the below snippet to call the stored proc,passing -1 for both begin and end.

```
String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(FIND_OFFICE_COUNT);
            SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(q);
            //qPos.add(lectureseriesId);
            List <Integer> sl =  (List<Integer>) QueryUtil.list(q, getDialect(), begin, end);   
            return sl;
```

In QueryUtil,we could not find other applicable methods to execute the call.
Post this we get the below error

```
ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-5][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
```

Is this approach correct with something missing or if not,please suggest approach to achieve the same.

Comment: It's strange to hear you need calla stored procedure, expacially to perform a count operation. Are you sure this is the right way?

Comment: @DanieleBaggio That is just for testing purpose as the actual was not working!

Answer (score 1):

there isn't any utility built-in  in liferay to call stored procedure but you can just get the connection with `DataAccess.getConnection();` and use the jdbc api like this way

```
 Connection connection =DataAccess.getConnection();
 CallableStatement cs  = connection.prepareCall("{Call proc_check(@output)}");
 ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Do you know how should be done if I add parameters? My stored procedure is like this: procedure_search_in_all(
   INOUT _return_serch_results DEFAULT NULL,
   created_date date,
   input_search varchar, 
   limit_results int
) I am using Liferay 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, try it.

```
session = openSession();
String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get(DELETE_BY_PROJETID);
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setCacheable(false);
QueryPos qPos = QueryPos.getInstance(query);
qPos.add(projectId);
query.executeUpdate();
```

https://web.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/37490823

Comment: I had tried this up but then how I get the output from the stored proc execution?