# Liferay 7.1.1 GA2 - How to encrypt database content?

Tags: mysql, encryption, liferay, liferay-7

I'm using Liferay CE Portal 7.1.1 GA2 with MySQL CE and want to add encryption to some user data.
MySQL only offers [TDE](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/tde.html) for the Enterprise Edition, so I want to use [column-level encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html) instead.

With Hibernate I'd use the `@ColumnTransformer` annotation. Is there a way, in Liferay CE 7.1.1 GA2, to change the entity to do it automatically?

I'd rather not do it on the Java-side, but if there's a hook mechanism or something similar that I can use, it would be great to know.

Comment: Did you read the caution in the MySQL manual?  "Passwords or other sensitive values supplied as arguments to encryption functions are sent in cleartext to the MySQL server unless an SSL connection is used. Also, such values will appear in any MySQL logs to which they are written. To avoid these types of exposure, applications can encrypt sensitive values on the client side before sending them to the server. The same considerations apply to encryption keys. To avoid exposing these, applications can use stored procedures to encrypt and decrypt values on the server side.
"

Comment: Yes, I did see the caution there. I don't want to encrypt passwords, I want to encrypt data in general. The stored procedure does not help my case because of Liferay.

Comment: "I don't want to encrypt passwords, I want to encrypt data in general. " I don't think you understand the manual on that topic or what i said about it.. Those encryping/decryping functions requires a "password" or better said a key cypher to encrypt/decrypt the data.

Comment: "The stored procedure does not help my case because of Liferay. " Well geuss what i [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926252/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-liferay)

Comment: I do understand that the secret will be in plain text, but it would be used by Liferay (if there's a way of setting it), and I think you don't understand my question. It's about setting up Liferay to call these functions (if that's even possible), I'm not concerned of how the secret will be stored in Liferay at the moment.

Comment: "and I think you don't understand my question." trust me i do " It's about setting up Liferay to call these functions (if that's even possible)," check mine last comment.

Comment: "Well geuss what i found": Well, I guess Liferay 6.2 is not 7.1.1, and it does not have default.xml anymore as it uses service builder instead and a different entity flow. I appreciate you trying to help, but this passive-aggressiveness is not helping much.

Comment: Well it seams 7.1 also supports custom queries.. https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/custom-sql.. What passive-aggressiveness?? you interpret it like that besides iám the only one who is commenting

Comment: Exactly! It supports queries. The question remains the same: how to encrypt the database content at the column level? As far as I know, queries cannot do that...

Comment: Is this question about encryption in your own custom entity, or is it about encrypting some of Liferay's own data?

Comment: @OlafKock, it is to encrypt a custom entity at column-level, similarly to what the hibernate annotation would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing that I know of that does automatic and transparent encryption. You can manually implement a [ModelListener](https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/model-listeners) to encapsulate the required implementation.

Under the hood, ServiceBuilder utilizes Hibernate, but I'm not aware of any support of `@ColumnTransformer`. Especially when it should survive another run of the code generator. However, you might want to look at the generated code on the persistence layer and just try it. Remember that there are plenty of future runs of the code generatur, so that you not only should test if you can insert the annotation, but you should also see if it survives the next generator run.

As yet another - but hard to maintain - option, you might want to look into ServiceBuilder's templates. I'd refrain from large-scale changes there, but if the change is minimal, there might be a point in making this change. In that case I'd recommend that you interact with Liferay (on the Liferay forums and issuetracker) to try getting it into the next version of ServiceBuilder.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I'll take a look at the template part. I tried to create an account and post in Liferay forums, but was not successful (system wouldn't log me in). I'll try again later.